# Difference between Category Home and Category Launcher

Tags: android, android-intent

I am not clear about what is the difference between category home and category launcher. From Android documentation page:

> CATEGORY_HOME : This is the home activity, that is the first activity
>   that is displayed when the device boots.
>
> CATEGORY_LAUNCHER : Should be displayed in the top-level launcher.

To test the difference I made a simple app with this manifest:

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".IntentCategoriesActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Second"
            android:label="Whatever" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>
```

But all I see is my launcher activity not the second activity.

Can somebody please explain what am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`android.intent.category.HOME` is used for Home Screen activities like ADW Launcher, Launcher Pro, etc. If you want to create a new home screen use this.

`android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` is used to specify which of your activities can be launched.  I.e. which ones show up in the app drawer.

Comment: Sorry what is ADW launcher? I am new to Android, quick googling says it is customizable android application?

Comment: ADW Launcher and Launcher Pro are home screen replacements. The grid of icons shows up when you first start your phone is the homescreen. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fede.launcher

Comment: What does top-level application launcher mean?

Answer (score 11):

`android.intent.category.HOME` - To be a launcher - this activity is homescreen
`android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` - To be **in** launcher - this activity is visible in menu

Answer (score -3):

In one manifest file ,there is only the first main is useful ,the second android.intent.action.MAIN is useless.